# Remote desktop sessions - Track/get the current location of user

Tags: powershell, terminal, windows-server-2008-r2, remote-desktop

I have been playing around with PSTermninalServices for a while, and I was wondering if it's possible to track, or get, the current location of the user that is holding, working directory, a remote desktop sessoin? E.g what folders are open and what files are opened by the user. Is this possible to achieve with scripting like PowerShell?

OS: Windows Server 2008 R2

Best regards.
DA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't know how to do it with PS, but you can use psfile (part of the excellent [pstools](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649.aspx) suite from Mark Russinovich )

```
psfile.exe [\\RemoteComputer [-u Username [-p Password]]] [[Id | path] [-c]]
     -u        Specifies optional user name for login to
               remote computer.
     -p        Specifies password for user name.
     Id        Id of file to print information for or close.
     Path      Full or partial path of files to match.
     -c        Closes file identified by file Id.
Omitting a file identifier has PsFile list all files opened remotely.
```